# Jmeter tearDown Thread Group can't access previous thread group used file

Tags: multithreading, csv, jmeter

I have a Test plan with several thread groups that write summary report results in the same csv file hosted in a server, this works fine using a networkdrive (z:) and changing jmeter.properties -> resultcollector.action_if_file_exists=APPEND.

Finally I have a tearDown Thread Group that insert the csv data into a sql server (the previous used networkdrive is hosted in this server in c:\jmeter\results.csv) and then it deletes the csv.
The case is when I run the test plan full I always have this error: *"Cannot bulk load because the file "c:\jmeter\results.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 32"*

The strange thing is that if I start the tearDown Thread Group alone it works fine, it makes the bulk insert in sql server and then it deletes de csv.

I started 2 days ago with Jmeter, so I'm sure I am misunderstanding something :S

[Summary Report Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaThv.png)

[JDBC Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znOKH.png)

[BeanShell PostProcessor that deletes csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/km4CY.png)

[Test plan Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WcUK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because Summary Report (as well as other listeners) **keep the file(s) open until test ends** so you need to trigger this "close" event somehow.

[Since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) therefore replace this Beanshell PostProcessor with the [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and use the following code:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.SearchByClass


def engine = engine = ctx.getEngine()
def test = engine.getClass().getDeclaredField('test')

test.setAccessible(true)

def testPlanTree = test.get(engine)

SearchByClass<ResultCollector> listenerSearch = new SearchByClass<>(ResultCollector.class)
testPlanTree.traverse(listenerSearch)
Collection<ResultCollector> listeners = listenerSearch.getSearchResults()

listeners.each { listener ->
    def files = listener.files
    files.each { file ->
        file.value.pw.close()
    }
}

new File('z:/result.csv').delete()
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)